# Neen help for a simple c program

Tags: c

Need help on a simple c program. Writing a TestValue program. The program runs but doesn't return a letter grade.
This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        double testValue;
        char getGrade;
        printf("Enter your score between o and 100:");
        scanf("%if", &testValue);
        printf("Your grade is %c\n", getGrade);
        return 1;
}
char getGrade(double value)
{
  if(value>=90)
    return'A';
  else if(value>=80)
    return'B';
  else if(value>=70)
    return'C';
  else if(value>=60)
    return'D';
  else if(value>=50)
    return'F';
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: The `main` function should return `0` when it terminates without an error, something unequal `0´ otherwise. In your example you basicly tell the OS that your program terminated with errors.

Comment: Asked the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832382/simple-correction-for-a-c-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%if` Should be `%lf`

You have not called the `getGrade` function

You have two identifiers with the same name.

Remove the `char getGrade;` declaration and just call the `getGrade` function.

Comment: +1 for providing instructions on how to figure out the problem instead of just giving them a copy/paste answer.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not convinced he/she did that :)

Comment: @sehe: It apparently worked. :-) I would have expanded with a little more detail, but not much more in the way of code. It's still much better than providing a copy and paste answer to an obvious homework/noob question.

Comment: Thanks it's working now, but It keeps returning the letter 'K'

Comment: @user1736391 I don't see how it can return 'K', unless you changed the code to include a 'K' grade.

Comment: I haven't changed anything. :/

Comment: You should also either put your `getGrade` function first, or use a forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to have the same name for a function and a variable.

You need to:

- Change `%if` to `%lf`
- Remove `char getGrade;`
- When calling the function, it should be `getGrade(testValue)`
- Change the function `char getGrade(double value)` to:

```c
char getGrades(double value)    
{    
  if(value>=90)    
    return 'A';    
  else if(value>=80)    
    return 'B';    
  else if(value>=70)    
    return 'C';    
  else if(value>=60)    
    return 'D';    
  return 'F';    
}
```

Comment: It keeps giving the letter k. I don't know why.. Help?

Comment: I tried it and it works fine on my computer, make sure that you changed what I told you and you didn't miss anything.

Comment: good answer. i would put the `return 'F';` inside an else. there would be no extra logic needed because the condition is already been tested. the benefit is that if something future coding error in the program causes some of the `if` logic to be skipped then the compiler will warn that the function is returning without a value.

Answer (score 0):

getGrade needs an argument getGrade(50) for example